# How do I run an Excel macro from Ruby?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, excel, vba

**Problem**

I have this ten something year old Excel workbook with a gazillion lines of VBA code in it some of which I have to update. So I had this crazy idea of writing unit tests in Ruby...

**Question**

How can I call an Excel macro from Ruby?

**What I have so far**

I have

- an Excel workbook called "C:\temp\Test.xlsm"
- with an sheet called "Sheet1" and
- a cell "A1".

Furthermore, this Excel workbook

- contains a module called "Module1"
- with a macro called `WriteToA1()` and
- another macro called `ClearA1()`

Plus, I have a Ruby script looking like this:

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'win32ole'

class TestDemo < Test::Unit::TestCase
   def testExcelMacro
    # Arrange
    excel = WIN32OLE.new("Excel.Application")
    excel.Visible = true
    excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\temp\Test.xlsm')

    # Act
    excel.run "Sheet1!WriteToA1"

    # Assert
    worksheet = excel.Workbooks.ActiveWorkbook
    assert_equal("blah", worksheet.Range("A1").Value)

    excel.Quit  
   end
end
```

**Exception**

I get this exception

```
WIN32OLERuntimeError: (in OLE method `run': )
    OLE error code:800A03EC in Microsoft Excel
      Cannot run the macro 'Sheet1!WriteToA1'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.
    HRESULT error code:0x80020009
      Exception occurred.
```

I have enabled all macros in Excel as described [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/enable-all-macros-in-excel-2010/).

Excel is being started, "Test.xlsm" is opened. Something must be wrong with the line:

```
excel.run "Sheet1!WriteToA1"
```

I have also tried this:

```
excel.run "Sheet1!Module1.WriteToA1"
```

Comment: Try this `excel.run "Test!WriteToA1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to provide the OLE module is the macro name

```
excel.run('WriteToA1')
```

Also note, if you want to run a macro with an arguement, you use:

```
excel.run('MarcoWithArgs', "Arg")
```

Comment: any chance that we could write / modify a marco using win32ole ?, or directly handle in ruby? some library wanted, which I could only find in "VBA Studio -> Reference", and I prefer the marco to be dynamically generated, any clue appeciated :) , @Lernkurve

Comment: Wow, I am looking for this solution too, I have a requirement of writing / modifying macro from ruby.