# How to run Excel from Golang or Nodejs on Window Server?

Tags: node.js, excel, go, windows-server

I'm using Excel on a Windows server to convert Excel to PDF. I want to know whether I can start Excel via Golang or Node.js on a Windows server. I see some examples of running Excel Application by Ruby, Python, C#.
For example:

- [Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963950/how-do-i-run-an-excel-macro-from-ruby):

```rb
require 'win32ole'

class TestDemo < Test::Unit::TestCase
   def testExcelMacro
    # Arrange
    excel = WIN32OLE.new("Excel.Application")
    excel.Visible = true
    excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\temp\Test.xlsm')

    # Act
    excel.run "Sheet1!WriteToA1"

    # Assert
    worksheet = excel.Workbooks.ActiveWorkbook
    assert_equal("blah", worksheet.Range("A1").Value)

    excel.Quit  
   end
end
```

- [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854840/xlsx-and-xlslatest-versions-to-pdf-using-python/20867193#20867193)

```py
from win32com import client
xlApp = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open('C:\\excel\\trial.xls')
ws = books.Worksheets[0]
ws.Visible = 1
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, 'C:\\excel\\trial.pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

If talk about `node.js` you can use [winax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winax) library or something similar for work with activex/com/dcom. But I believe you can use just build-in in windows javascript interpreter (not node.js) for it.